# Oracle to MySQL Migration (AL32UTF8 to latin1)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate the Oracle database to MySQL(Aurora).
On Oracle the character set is AL32UTF8:

`SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_CHARACTERSET';`

and on MySQL is latin1:

```
SELECT character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_schema = "MySchema"
  AND table_name = "tableName"
  AND column_name = "columnName";
```

The issue is that not all the varchar2 fields from Oracle are converted correctly to varchar MySQL.
Ex. `source column : 'ColumnName', value : 'Bo musz co wpisa ' not matching with target column : 'ColumnName', value : 'Bo musz? co? wpisa? '`

I would avoid changing the source Oracle DB, instead, I prefer to change the MySQL DB.

What would be the best corresponding character set on MySQL?
Thanks

Comment: Try `utf8mb4` character set instead of `latin1`.

Comment: There are a number of aspects to this. 1st, how the data in Oracle is stored. 2nd how the data is rendered when it is SELECTed and transported. 3 How the data is stored in the target. Most focus on 1 and 3, but in my experience it is 2 that needs careful thought too. In a nutshell, make sure that when you SELECT the data from Oracle, the `NLS_LANG` setting is set correctly. This applies to sqlplus, expdp/impdp, JDBC, ODBC (my.cnf config) environments. Experiment setting different values then running sqlplus until the output is displayed correctly then migrate with that value set.